# Create new events with Office 365 API

Tags: asp.net, office365api

I got `Error 401 Not Authorized`:

I already configured everything, the below code is running through Button:

```
//Karim
string postData = "{\"Subject\": \"Discuss the Calendar REST API\",\"Body\": {\"ContentType\": \"HTML\",\"Content\": \"I think it will meet our requirements!\"},\"Start\": {\"DateTime\": \"2016 - 02 - 02T18: 00:00\",\"TimeZone\": \"Pacific Standard Time\"},\"End\": {\"DateTime\": \"2016 - 02 - 02T19: 00:00\",\"TimeZone\": \"Pacific Standard Time\"}}";
string Url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events";
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

this.Label1.Text = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

myStreamReader.Close();
responseStream.Close();

myHttpWebResponse.Close();
//End Karim
```

I already configured Office 365 Developer tools, NuGet, I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Just two coding tips. 1 do not mix the UI code `this.Label1.Text` with the web requests logic. 2. you should use the C# keyword [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request must be authenticated and authorized in order to be able to request these APIs. Indeed who would be the "/me" if you do not provide any information on whose behalf you are doing such a request?

To do this you are supposed to set a so called authentication bearer, which in your C# .NET call will look like something like this

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<your access token as string here>");
```

To learn how do you retrieve such an access token, start with [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#using-the-calendar-rest-api).